# dbWriteTable(..., append = T) is overwritng in R

Tags: mysql, r, analytics

I am using RJDBC for accessing MySQL from R. Earlier I used to work with RMySQL which is not available for R 2.15. There were so many discussions around SO but still I couldn't able to use RMySQL package in R 2.15 so switched to RJDBC.

When I'm using `dbWriteTable(..., append = T)` command for appending records into MySQL table it is simply overwriting, please see the code below.

## setting environment variable for MySQL server

```
Sys.setenv(MYSQL_HOME='C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1')

library(RJDBC)
```

## MySQL connection

```
drv <- JDBC("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar", "`")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "Retail", user="root", password="abc")
..................
..................
..................
dbWriteTable(conn, "Customer_Tbl", x, row.names=F,append = T)
```

`Customer_Tbl` is overwriting everytime instead of appending.

Can somebody help in how to tackle this issue?

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: Suresh, what was the outcome of this issue?  Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 11):

You need to use overwrite=FALSE, following sample code:

```
dbWriteTable(connection, name=tableName, value=rows , append=T, row.names=F, overwrite=F);
```