# dbwritetable removes auto increment field in mysql

Tags: mysql, r

I am working with MySql for the first time.  I have created a database in mysql with some tables using PHPMYADMIN.  One of the table is titled as "City". This table as two column fields 1. City_ID and 2. City.  In this City_ID is the primary key with auto increment.

I have the data in CSV format, which I have read into R.  From the data frame, I am using the following command to get the City values from R - DF.

```
City <- as.data.frame(unique(df[,10]))
names(City) <- "City"
```

I am using the following codes to connect with MySql.

```
library(RMySQL)
mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "root", password = "****", dbname = "pal", host = "localhost")

dbWriteTable(mydb, "City", City, overwrite = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

This removes the field City_ID and fills the City column of the table with values.  Don't know how to resolve this.  Most of the work that I do has data in excel or csv formats.  And I need to frequently update the tables too.  Any thoughts on this.

Comment: You *did* specify `overwrite = TRUE`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dbWriteTable(..., append = T) is overwritng in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719850/dbwritetable-append-t-is-overwritng-in-r)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did try with `overwrite = FALSE` along with append = T but i am getting only zero as values in my sql table.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is the problem at this case too. [LAST_INSERT_ID() always returns 0 (RMySQL) - separate connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246412/last-insert-id-always-returns-0-rmysql-separate-connection-issue) as Illari wrote at different topic.

```
library("RMySQL")
con <- dbConnect(MySQL())
dbSendQuery(con, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;")
dbSendQuery(con, "CREATE TABLE t (i INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);")
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL);")

doesn't work:
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")
  LAST_INSERT_ID()
1                0

# works:
dbClearResult(rs)
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")
  LAST_INSERT_ID()
1                1
```